# iOS app signing and ownership

Tags: android, ios, keystore, android-keystore

I have a question regarding moving the ownership of the iOS app to other developers. On Android you only need signing key and keystore (jks file), whoever has access to that can create app ready for Google Store. I wonder what is necessary to do the same on iOS since there are provisioning profiles, certificates and different things involved.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS, you don't need that developer apple account. Then log in to iTunesConnect you will see user and roles option go inside it. There you can add a user for specific apps you want to give ownership.

Answer (score 1):

Only two thing you have to do...

1. Send `p12 file` of Distribution-Certificate with its private key and `CSR file`
2. Add the developer as per role you required at developer.apple.com.

**Apple Developer Program Team Roles**

**Team Agent**
Available to developers enrolled as an individual or an organization
The person who completes enrollment automatically becomes the Team Agent. There can only be one Team Agent.

**Admin**
Available only to developers enrolled as an organization
Admins serve as a secondary contact for teams and have many of the same responsibilities as Team Agents.

**Member**
Available only to developers enrolled as an organization
Members have access to membership benefits, but have limited responsibilities.

https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/